# Calculating sum of a string using lettervalues

Tags: python, string, sum

I have spent way too much time trying to solve what seems to be a pretty easy task.

I have assigned some letters/variables with different values. Ex:

```
o,b,c,d,e,f = 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

and I want to find the "sum" of a string containing any of the letters, like this:

```
'coffee' = 3+1+6+6+5+5
```

Is there an easy/fast way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
lettermap = {
  'o': 1,
  'b': 2,
   ...
}

print sum(lettermap[c] for c in 'coffee')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the structure of a [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) and [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#sum):

```
>>> dct = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> sum(dct[ch] for ch in 'aab')
4
```