# How to find the sum of a word

Tags: python, string, sum

For one of my programs we have to assign number values to every letter, and then take the user input and find the sum of the letter/their number values. Here's my code so far:

```
import string 

L = raw_input("Type your list of strings here (follow each string with a comma): ").split(",")
print L
n = len(L)
List = L[0:n]
counter = 0
x = L[counter]
y = L[counter + 1]

d1 = {c: L for L,c in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase, 1)}
d1['A'] = 1
d1['B'] = 2
d1['C'] = 3
d1['D'] = 4
d1['E'] = 5
d1['F'] = 6
d1['G'] = 7
d1['H'] = 8
d1['I'] = 9
d1['J'] = 10
d1['K'] = 11
d1['L'] = 12
d1['M'] = 13
d1['N'] = 14
d1['O'] = 15
d1['P'] = 16
d1['Q'] = 17
d1['R'] = 18
d1['S'] = 19
d1['T'] = 20
d1['U'] = 21
d1['V'] = 22
d1['W'] = 23
d1['X'] = 24
d1['Y'] = 25
d1['Z'] = 26
d1['a'] = 1
d1['b'] = 2
d1['c'] = 3
d1['d'] = 4
d1['e'] = 5
d1['f'] = 6
d1['g'] = 7
d1['h'] = 8
d1['i'] = 9
d1['j'] = 10
d1['k'] = 11
d1['l'] = 12
d1['m'] = 13
d1['n'] = 14
d1['o'] = 15
d1['p'] = 16
d1['q'] = 17
d1['r'] = 18
d1['s'] = 19
d1['t'] = 20
d1['u'] = 21
d1['v'] = 22
d1['w'] = 23
d1['x'] = 24
d1['y'] = 25
d1['z'] = 26
d1[''] = 0
d1[','] = 0


def compare(x, y):
    p = 0
    score = sum(d1[c] for c in L)
    score1 = score(x[p])
    score2 = score(y[p])
```

I can get it to work fine when the user input is a singular string but I can't get it to work when the user inputs a list of strings. I need to be able to input a list, and then be able to find the numerical value of any particular string in the list. Please help me find where I am going wrong, because I don't understand why this code doesn't work.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] and a clearer problem description than *"isn't running properly"*.

Comment: Have you looked at this question already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572315/calculating-sum-of-a-string-using-lettervalue ?

Comment: Ever heard of [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)?

Comment: yes I have, my prof. is making us create the dictionary manually.

Comment: meltdown90 yes I have, as stated in my post I can find the sum of a singular string just fine. I'm having issues finding the sum of a list of strings and storing them spearatly

Comment: Have you tried using for loop? Like, `for word in listOfStrings: doSumForSingleString` etc. and create a dictionary for storing. Strings as keys and their sum as values.

Comment: lafexlos: the user can input any combination of letters so creating a dictionary of every possible combination is out of the question. And are the only issue with using the of loop you described is I also need to be able to compare numerical values of particular letters in words also.

Comment: What do you mean by _compare_? If your strings are "abc", "abd", "abe", shouldn't you get {"abc": 6, "abd": 7, "abe": 8} or something like that?

Comment: lafexlos: lets say I have a list L = ["abc", "abd", "abe"].  I need to be able to compare L[0][0] with L[1][0]. which is comparing the first letter of the first string with the first letter of the second string

Comment: And what is has to do with summation? You should include those kind of details in your original post. There is not a single mention about it.

Comment: lafexlos: Because if you actually would answer the question I originally posted I could figure out how to do what I just described. If someone can explain how I can find the sum of a string in a list, I can find how to find the value of an individual letter in the string. There is no need to be rude.

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude. Sorry if I was. I was just trying understand your question.

Comment: And your question still unclear to me. You are saying -in your question- you want to find sum of a string in list of strings which can be accomplished by these 3 lines of code. `def summation(word): return sum(lettersDict[s.upper()] for s in word); sums= {word: summation(word) for word in listOfStrings}`

Answer (score 0):

I finally remembered where I do know this problem. Good old Euler 22.

In comments you said you would sort *while or after* the calculation of word's score. Instead sort the names first, right after splitting and getting names. Python's [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) is actually pretty fast one. Then use [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) on sorted list. With enumerate you can keep track of indexes which will make things quite easy.

Spoilers below. Since spoiler markup doesn't work well with code blocks, gotta do it like this.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

```
import string

lettersDict = {c: L for L,c in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase, 1)}
lettersDict[" "] = 0
lettersDict[","] = 0
lettersDict["\""] = 0

def summation(word): 
    return sum(lettersDict[s.upper()] for s in word)

total = 0
with open("names.txt","r") as f:
    names = f.read().split(",")
    names.sort()                    
    for idx, word in enumerate(names, 1):
        total += idx*summation(word)

print total
```